# Android service does not re-started after application is force closed.

Tags: android, service

I started my service properly, its working well. I write condition that if service is already running then it don't start service again. condition returns true values which shows that service is running. But whenever I force stop my application, or if any exception occurred, my service stops loading data at background and till showing that service is running. That's why service is not re-started.

Intent that I used to start service from activity :

```
this.startService(new Intent(MainMenu1.this, MovieService.class));
```

And My service class is :

public class MovieService extends Service {

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TBD
    Log.i("Movie Service : "," Created2");
    new MovieDownloaderTask().execute();
    return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
    //return Service.START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
 public void onCreate() {
  Log.i("Movie Service : "," Created");

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     Log.d("Movie Service","onDestroy was Called!");
     super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
     Log.i("Movie Service : "," Started");

 }

 public class MovieDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> 
    {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i("Movie Service"," : Started2");
            //Moviejson.createDB();

            try
            {
                Moviejson.insert_Movie_Data();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Exception > ", "i m in doInBackground. Trying to stop Movie service.");
                MovieService.this.stopSelf();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 1;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (result == 1) {

                if(MainMenu1.Movies_new_time==null)
                {
                    MainMenu1.Movies_new_time=MainMenu1.sp.getMovies_Old_Date();
                }
                else
                {
                    MainMenu1.sp.setMovies_Current_Date(MainMenu1.Movies_new_time);
                }
                MainMenu1.sp.setMovies_Current_Date(MainMenu1.Movies_new_time);

                Log.i("Movie Date:", " : "+MainMenu1.Movies_new_time);

                MovieService.this.stopSelf();
                Log.i("Movie Service"," : Stoped");
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `onStartCommand()`, replace

```
return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
```

with

```
return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT
```